# What does "hit the data" and "hit a question" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Both sentences were found in the context of academic research. The full sentences would be

> looking for as much data as possible around the world and trying to hit it as hardly as I can
>
> It provides an opportunity to hit this question much more hard.

Comment: I'm afraid neither of them makes sense to me. The first one isn't a sentence: it lacks a subject, and misuses the word 'hardly'. You can't hit something *hardly*, though you *can* hit something hard. You can't hit data, though you *can* hit the screen it appears on, or the paper it's printed on. The second sentence has the same problem: you can't hit a question. And 'Much more hard' is almost always abbreviated to 'harder.'

Comment: Both sentences were probably written by someone whose English is imperfect – although I would not be surprised to see *attack* in either.  In both I think the intended meaning is to apply all available analytical tools.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian It's not hard to hardly hit someone, but it means you don't hit them hard.

Comment: @user105719 Yes but your to hardly hit is hardly his to hit hardly surely.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Assuredly.

Comment: to hit it as hardly as I can? That is a huge English mistake. So the "research" is BS. Both sentence are **terrible** English. My goodness. I wonder *where you found them*. Some comment on a blog??

Answer (score 1):

We probably need more context but it can mean something similar to “[hit the books](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_the_books)” and to study it intensely and determinedly.

If I was to “*hit a question hard*” it would probably be a controversial question that would be hit with every fact and counter point in order to stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: That explains it. "hit the books: mainly US and Australian English informal." Not yet in the UK, though we do hit the bottle, the road and the sack, in that order.